# R check if a variable is a factor

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a loop which can apply to a dataframe.  The loop will basically check each variable in the dataframe and tell me which variable is a factor.

An example:

```
test1<-c("red","red","blue","yellow")
test1<-as.factor(test1)
test2<-c(1,2,3,4)

variable<-c("test1","test2")
count<-2

for (i in 1:count)
{
        if (is.factor(paste(variable[i]))==TRUE) 
        { 
           print("This is a factor")
        }
}
```

test1 variable is supposed to be a factor and therefore the sentence "This is a factor" should be printed.  However nothing happened.  I wonder why?

Comment: `paste` does not come close to doing what you think it does.  Please read `?paste` , `?get`, `?eval`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is an evaluation problem. The character arrays "test1" or "test2" are not factors.

```
> is.factor(get(variable[1]))
[1] TRUE
> is.factor(get(variable[2]))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sapply` or `lapply` instead of you for-loop as follows:

```
variable <- data.frame(test1,test2)
sapply(variable,is.factor) # returns a vector
test1 test2 
 TRUE FALSE

lapply(variable,is.factor) # returns a list
$test1
[1] TRUE

$test2
[1] FALSE
```

Or you can easily use your function instead of `is.factor`

**Edit:** (thanks to Ananda Mahto)
`vapply` is even faster than `sapply`

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  vapply(variable,is.factor, c(is.factor=FALSE)),
  sapply(variable,is.factor),
  lapply(variable,is.factor),
  times = 10000
)
Unit: microseconds
                                              expr    min     lq median     uq      max neval
 vapply(variable, is.factor, c(is.factor = FALSE)) 12.248 13.829 14.618 15.409  959.698 10000
                       sapply(variable, is.factor) 31.608 35.560 36.350 37.534 1159.618 10000
                       lapply(variable, is.factor)  9.877 11.458 11.853 12.644  935.597 10000
```

Comment: Why are you neglecting `vapply` :-)

Comment: Thanks! Never used vapply before. But i am going to in the future